# Регулярные выражения и модификатор /s

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Здравствуйте.

В PHP имеется модификатор /s. Согласно документации:

> /s - если необходимо, что бы поиск был
> по всему тексту, не обращая внимания
> на перенос строки;

Что это означает и в каких случая применять этот модификатор? Я пробовал в использовании разные регулярные выражения, убирая или наоборот подставляя этот модификатор, а различий никаких. Хоть он есть, хоть его нет. Даже, если в тексте имеются переносы строки. Так зачем тогда нужен этот модификатор? Спасибо.

Comment: @stashappy, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Это вы об [этой "документации"](https://www.site-do.ru/php/regularnie.php)? Это чьё-то личное иносказание. Кстати, "что бы" пишется слитно в данном случае.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если стоит модификатор `s`, метасимвол `.` будет совпадать в том числе с переносом строки, иначе нет.